# How do I move an already under-development website in a folder on localhost to a specific repository on Github Pages for the first time?

Tags: git, gitlab, synchronization, push, clone

I have a website on my localhost (apache2) that I want to copy to a repository on Github. When I initialize a git repository on my localhost, another folder is created, however, development is not happening in that folder. I don't understand how to push the files in my localhost development environment to a repository on GitHub pages.

Comment: Can you describe how you "initialize a git repository" ? from the cli ? from your IDE ?  What actions do you execute ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already created a new repository on GitHub? There are some good instructions there for how to add existing code that you have locally.

I am also assuming that you have git set up already? Instructions for this can also be found on GitHub's Quickstart guide.
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/getting-started-with-github/quickstart

It sounds like you might have called `git init <directory>` which creates a new directory. You just need to call `git init` to transform the current working directory into a fully fledged git repository. From your terminal of choice navigate to your source directory and do something like the following:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:[[your git username here]]/[[your repo name here]].git
git push -u origin main
```

You might want to consider also adding a .gitignore file so that git ignores